# Add email tab in storybook mode in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am new in IOS, I need to add email address in storyboard mode. do i need to add code? where?

Comment: Please be a lot more specific. What do you need to do? Is your email address? A form for user to write to you?

Comment: I have this app that i made in fully starboard mode, in one of the page i need embed page with label and link for email.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is a good starting point -  My First iOS app: [Link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/00_Introduction.html)